# Bit manipulation to determine if all "movement" of set bits was to the left

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

When a binary integer's value changes, we can describe that change as "only left movement" if the new value can be formed using only these two operations:

1. Clear a set bit
2. Clear a set bit, and then set any unset bit to the left of the bit that was cleared

Some examples:

```
10101010 -> 10101100 # valid
10011000 -> 10010000 # valid
11111111 -> 00000001 # valid
00000000 -> 00010000 # invalid
10000011 -> 01110000 # invalid
10001010 -> 10101100 # invalid
```

I have this function that works fine (for non-negative 32-bit integers):

```py
def only_left(a, b):
    a, b = bin(a)[2:][::-1].zfill(32), bin(b)[2:][::-1].zfill(32)
    ac = bc = 0
    for i, j in zip(a, b):
        ac += int(i == '1')
        bc += int(j == '1')
        if bc > ac:
            return False
    return True
```

My question is, can this be done without any type conversion or loops, using only bitwise and arithmetic operators (`& | ^ ~ + - * / %`)? I know the function above can be written using `>>` and `&` in a loop, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in one step (no loops).

Comment: I am not sure that i understand the examples. Can you explain some more as to which bits are set and which are cleared and why it is valid or invalid.

Comment: Also, if you have this algorithm in a loop, Why do you need it without a loop. And why is there a restriction on using only arithmetic operators?

Comment: Doesn't this come to case where the bit strings on the left should always be greater than the ones in right? invalid if they are not?

Comment: Your code return True for `00000000 -> 00010000`

Comment: Can you clarify the wording of your rules? What do you mean by "Clear an unset bit"? The gist seems to be that the only way to have ``0``->``1`` is as part of ``01`` -> ``10``. Is that correct?

Comment: Original wording was “clear a set bit.” I updated the question with a corrected function that should handle the case ikegami mentioned, and reverted the wording.

Comment: Can you explain how `11111111 -> 00000001 # valid` is valid? From your question I thought only one bit could be reset.

Comment: @J...S The two operations described can be executed zero or more times.